# Why CMake doubles the path?

Tags: cmake

I am using UseLATEX, with commands

```
set(MainFile "Demo.tex")    
set(InputFiles ${MainFile} Main.tex OtherFiles.tex)
```

then later I use it like

```
  ADD_LATEX_DOCUMENT( ${MyFileName}  
    INPUTS     "${InputFiles}" )
```

and everything works fine. If I change to

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE InputFiles src/*.tex)
```

then I receive messages with a list of files I wanted to put into InputFiles,
but preceeded with

```
"Could not find input file ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/OtherFiles.tex"
```

and of course that path does not exist. What is wrong?

Comment: Haven't worked with `ADD_LATEX_DOCUMENT()`, but it seems it would need relative paths. Please try `file(GLOB_RECURSE InputFiles RELATIVE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" src/*.tex)`.

Comment: @Florian Yes, that was it. If you convert your comment to answer, I could accept it.

Comment: Glad I could help. Added my comment as an answer.

Comment: @katang I think you should accept Florian's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comment into answer*

Haven't worked with `ADD_LATEX_DOCUMENT()`, but it seems it appends the current directory itself and would need relative paths.

Just change your `file(GLOB ...)` command to output relative paths:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE InputFiles RELATIVE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" src/*.tex)
```